# Doubly linked list implementation shows segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

This is my code-snippet for DLL implementation.

```
struct node  //doubly-linked list
{
    int data;
    struct node *next; // next-pointer
    struct node *prev; // previous-pointer
};

typedef struct node *node;

struct LL  //LL has a field 'head' pointing to top of the list
{
    node head;

};

typedef struct LL *LL;

node CREATE_NODE(int k)
{
    node temp;
    temp = (node)malloc( sizeof (node));
    
    if (temp == NULL)
    exit(0);

    temp->data= k;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
      LL list;
      list->head = NULL;//segmentation error
      return 0;
}
```

Since I was asked to implement the doubly linked list using typedef initialization in the question, is there any other way to initialize the head pointer to make it NULL?

Edit: Added some extra code to display the insert function.

```
void INSERT(LL l, int k) //insert at the front only
   {

    node y;
    y = CREATE_NODE(k); //create an empty list first

    y->next = l->head;  //next-pointer points to the head
    y->prev = NULL;

    if (l->head!= NULL)
    {
       (l->head)->prev = y;
    }

    l->head = y; 
    }
```

Comment: Having a struct named `LL` and a typedef with the same name that is a pointer to the type can be confusing. What is `list` pointing to in `main`?

Comment: It's a linked list. Basically it contains the head pointer to transverse the list. It has only the 'head' element and it should be pointing to NULL before I use it.

Comment: @rubenskx Sure, but you need an instance of the linked list structure, not a pointer to a linked list structure. You've painted yourself into a corner by typedefing LL as a pointer. It is very bad practice to typedef pointers.

Comment: So in main function I should call struct LL *pointer instead of LL pointer. But shouldn't I allocate space for the pointer?

Comment: You should first change the typedef to `typedef struct LL LL;` Then in `main`, all you need is `LL list = {NULL};`

Comment: Ok, but I use the LL pointer in functions as a parameter for list operations. Is there any other way that I can initialize it without changing the typedef?

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous issues with your code. The major foot-shot was fired from this line:

```
typedef struct LL *LL;
```

Now `LL` is a pointer to `struct LL`. Hiding a pointer in a `typedef` is considered a very bad practice with only acceptable exception of function pointers.

Therefore code:

```
LL list;
```

declares uninitialized pointer to `struct LL`.
Dereferencing this pointer in `list->head` invokes Undefined behavior, likely caused by *NULL dereference* and receiving `SEGFAULT` signal.

I guess the intention was:

```
struct LL list;
list.head = NULL;
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error at the point where the head is initialized to NULL. Is there any way to initialize the head pointer such that I don't get the segmentation fault while using typedef?

Comment: @rubenskx do you have any extra code after initialization of head? If so then share it , pleade

Comment: pls check the edited question for the insertion at the front of the list.